# Can anyone explain the ohm's law apply here?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ohms-law, kirchhoffs-laws, phasor

What i am seeking is to explain why the relationship here is not V2/R2 instead it's given as (V1-V2)/R2

[image]

Comment: V2 is the voltage across *both* resistors.

Comment: yeah,but why? i mean R1 doesn't seem to have any relationship with V2.Am i examinating it with the wrong scope? @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: You have noticed that there is a 2H inductor in that circuit I hope.

Comment: Do you see where ground on the circuit is located?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yeah,so?

Comment: All voltages are referenced to ground.

Comment: The voltage *across R2* is V2 - V1 where both V1 and V2 are referenced to ground.

Comment: so i got the wrong approach,thank u so so much guys!

Comment: You have a constant current source as well by the way

Comment: BTW V2 = 0V because the ideal L has R=0 so for Ohm's law We ignore methods of calculation in frequency domain and let s=0 or f=0 and simplify the model to just Ohm's Law, so then ......  V1 = =IR = I*0.5 for R=1/2 Ohm and I= current source

Comment: Read about nodal analysis technique.

Answer (score 1):

Because ohm's law is actually:

$$\Delta V=RI <=> Va-Vb=RI_{ab}$$

Where ***Va*** is the voltage at one terminal of the resistor, and ***Vb*** is the voltage at the other terminal. I just added the little index to the current so that you know its direction.

The delta is often omitted for simplicity, and this usually leads to a lot of confusion from beginners.

Comment: Sometimes Ohm's Law is used like $$ ESR= $$ $$ \Delta V \over \Delta I $$

Comment: In the context of my answer, ΔV is the *difference in potential* across the resistor, which is the same as the *difference* of the **potential differences in relation to ground** (voltages ***Va*** and ***Vb***) at the terminals of the resistor.

When calculating ESR you are actually taking the difference between voltages for different currents, like when trying to calculate resistance from a diode's I-V curve, so in that case  ΔV means a voltage difference (a differance in potential difference in relation to ground) and not strictly a potential difference.

Comment: Of course, understading that a *difference of potential differences* is **the same** as a *potential difference* is very confusing for beginners and heck, even for some professionals, but that's what we get for not having an absolute 0 potential reference. I'm not saying that we should have one though, as that would be as stupid as defining a universal "0 height" for calculating gravitational potentials in different planets.

Comment: when you get 20 to 40 yrs experience , you will know the difference very well. I was actually referring to the linear region of a nonlinear component, circuit or network using simply, Ohm's Law.  try to keep it real.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the difficulty, at all. With currents spilling outward on the left and currents spilling inward on the right, I get:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_1}{R_1} + \frac{V_1}{R_2} &= \frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{R_1} + \frac{V_2}{R_2} + i_s \\
 \\
\frac{V_1}{R_1} + \frac{V_1}{R_2} &= \frac{V_2}{R_2} + i_s \\
 \\
\frac{V_1}{R_1} + \frac{V_1}{R_2} - \frac{V_2}{R_2} &= i_s \\
 \\
\frac{V_1}{R_1} + \frac{V_1-V_2}{R_2} &= i_s
\end{align*}$$

I'm really flummoxed why you can't get there. But you haven't really exposed your thinking much, either.

As an aside, another way of writing the second node is:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_2}{R_2} + \frac{1}{L} \int V_2\:\textrm{d}t &= \frac{V_1}{R_2} \\
  \\
\frac{1}{L} \int V_2\:\textrm{d}t &= \frac{V_1-V_2}{R_2}
\end{align*}$$

But, assuming \$i_s\$ is a constant current source, your circuit can also be reduced to a voltage source with a series resistance into an inductor. So a DC voltage and an R+L load.